# IDE for Objective C

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, ide

What are the IDE's or development tools best suited for projects involving Objective C, C and C++?  Is there a common IDE which would support all the three languages.

Comment: A plugin for Objective C support in eclipse CDT would have been good.

Comment: Moreover I would be needing it work on a linux system. 'vi with CScope' and Eclipse would help for C/C++ development, but I think, not objective-C. Will have to try emacs.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Objective-C for macos or iphone apps it seems there is no way around [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/index.html) from Apple. Xcode has many tools like an Iphone emulator and a profiler for Iphone and macos applications.

For c and c++ I personally would use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

Comment: While I greatly differ in opinion about Eclipse here, I've stated before that my entire office *hates* Macs yet 1/2 the people there have them up full time for the iPhone apps they make. If you're serious about Objective-C development, then you'll either get a Mac/Xcode, or shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 5):

[Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technology/Xcode.html), [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/), [Cocoatron](http://www.cocotron.org/), [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/)

If Objective-C is your main goal, and you have access to a mac, Xcode is your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

For Objective-C (on the Mac) it's [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), which comes with Mac OS X. It's on the installation DVD. The latest version can be downloaded, for free, from the [Apple Developer Connection site](http://developer.apple.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going with XCode, I would suggest without hesitation using EMACS.  I just picked it up with help from the [Peepcode](http://peepcode.com/products/meet-emacs) screencast, and I haven't looked back.  Even using Visual Studio at work I've now switched to Emacs for every language besides C# (i.e. Javascript, HTML, CSS, Ruby, etc...).  It's a bottomless pit of features, in a good and bad way.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some else asks this question and lands here.

There are a few programmers text editors that support Objective-C, but I like Editra, mainly because I also write Python on Windows\Nix and it has great features. Editra runs well on all platforms and has a nice plug-in that supports Mercurial, GIT, and Subversion if you need them. Another nice thing, its written in Python. [Editra Home](http://editra.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this iDE. It can use with simulator, instrument,...

I think its core is the same with eclipse core

http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is really the only way to go. If you are crazy-bad-ass and try to use GNUstep and Project Center, you may run into lots of bugs and fail.

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C you really want to be using a Mac so you can take advantage of the Cocoa, although I have heard good things about using The Cocotron so you can develop cross-platform using Objective-C.

As an IDE I'd either use Xcode or Textmate.

I find Textmate better for if I'm just hacking on some code - I prefer its colour schemes and being able to define and use my own snippets and macros. Also it has support for lots more languages than XCode but it isn't as fully featured.

Also here is a little article about porting Objective-C to Windows using The Cocotron [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/porting-mac-program-to-windows-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SlickEdit: http://www.slickedit.com

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install the GNUstep ProjectCenter on a Windows machine and it crashed Windows.  I am going to try [the latest FreeBSD release](http://www.freebsd.org/releases/9.0R/announce.html), which incorporates Clang, a rival of gcc with a BSD licence instead of a GPL licence.  The whole thing seems very well put together.