# Cross-platform C++ IDE that also supports Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ide, objective-c++

I have a few projects where most of the code is written in platform-agnostic C++, with a relatively thin platform abstraction layer for each supported platform. For most platforms this abstraction layer is also written in C++, but for iOS and OSX it also contains some Objective-C code. For this reason, I have Xcode projects for the iOS / OSX builds, and Visual Studio projects for Windows, but I'm a bit tired of having to maintain multiple project files.

It would be so nice to only have one cross-platform IDE, one project file for that IDE, then just add all source files to that, and make some of them included in the build only in certain configurations. But for that I'd need an IDE that runs on multiple platforms (Windows, OSX, preferably linux too), and supports not only C++, but Objective-C source files as well. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114305/ide-for-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

You can try QtCreator. It's a cross-platform IDE developed for Qt but it supports Objective-c too:
http://qt-project.org/downloads